# We might buy a larger house if we had more money

Tags: modal-verbs

1. We **might** buy a larger house *if we had more money*.

Q: Is the conditional clause talking about our current state or our future state?

a) We **might** buy a larger house in the future *if we had more money* (in the future).

b) We **might** buy a larger house now *if we had more money* (now).

Comment: It could be either.

Comment: "Might" requires "have", so the options are: "We might buy a new house if we have more money" /  "We would buy a new house if we had more money".

Comment: *if we **had** more money* refers to a "timeless, counterfactual" state of affairs, so it's meaningless to ask whether the cited example refers to having more money ***now*** or ***in the future***.  On the other hand, *if we **have** more money* can normally *only* refer to a future state (if it *does* refer to the present, that just implies speaker *doesn't yet know* if they have "more" money, so effectively it's referring to a future time when speaker finds out the current financial position).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct.

"Might" in this context indicates a *future possibility*, but you are tying to your *present* financial position by saying "if we *had* more money". It doesn't make sense because buying a bigger house doesn't become possible until you have enough money.

You could say instead:

> We **might** buy a larger house if we **have** more money.

This ties a future possibility to a possible future financial position.

or

> We **could** (or *would*) buy a larger house if we **had** more money.

This ties a present hypothetical possibility/certainty to a hypothetical financial position.

Comment: I think these sentences don't work either: 1) *We **might** save enough money if you **worked** overtime*. 2) *If I **had** enough money, I **might** go to Paris today*. Am I rihgt?

Comment: Those sentences look fine to me, and so does "We might buy (would have the option of buying) a larger house if we had more money [now]."

Comment: Thank you both! I really appreciate your answers/comments. :)